# Remove glossary title

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package to put a list of terms at the end, and have created an appendix which is titled "Appendix A Glossary".  The problem is that when I use:

```
\begin{appendices}
\section{Glossary}
\printnoidxglossary
\end{appendices}
```

I get the section title, then "Glossary" (the glossary title) on a new line, then the glossary contents.  What I would like is just the section title followed by the glossary contents.

Using `\printnoidxglossary[title={}]` to set the title to empty still displays a blank line.  Using `\renewcommand\glossaryname{}` or `\renewcommand*\glossaryname{}` results in the same.  I would like this white space gone as well.

Here's a screenshot of the output I get: [image: screen1]

I would like to get rid of the glossary title line, but have found nothing in the user manual or on any google searches that accomplishes this.

Heres a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\loadglsentries{terms.tex}
\makenoidxglossaries
\begin{document}
...
\tableofcontents
...
\begin{appendices}
\section{Glossary}
\printnoidxglossary
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

`terms.tex` just contains the definitions, currently:

```
\newacronym{pc}{PC}{Player Character}
\newacronym{hud}{HUD}{Heads-Up Display}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). But can't you just say something like `\renewcommand*\glossaryname{}`?

Comment: We can't compile that without `terms.tex`...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about it clearing the glossary and the table of contents. There isn't even a table of contents in your example. But, anyway, see page 31 of the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,numberedsection]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief.tex}
\makenoidxglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\begin{appendices}
  \printnoidxglossary
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: glossary as appendix]

Comment: @LEGEND383 Good. Definitely an XY problem, then. That is, you thought you wanted to do X but actually, you wanted to do Y ;).